# Compute stat_summary with lines drawn between points, not raw data in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean

I have some data that are missing some observations, e.g.,

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dframe <- data.frame(height = c(1, 2, NA, 4, 
                                 1.2, 2.5, 3.8, 4.4,
                                 3, NA, 5, 7),
                     name = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4),
                     date = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 3))
```

So data look like this:

```
   height name date
1    1.0    A    1
2    2.0    A    2
3     NA    A    3
4    4.0    A    4
```

But, in my data, NA values don't actually exist, so dframe is actually:

```
dframe <- dframe %>% 
  filter(!height %in% NA)
```

I'd like to create a plot for the data where I show the raw data for each "name" - A, B, and C - and also have a "mean height" line. I try using:

```
ggplot(dframe, aes(date, height)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = name), color = "blue") +
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line", size = 1) +
  theme_bw()
```

**But, as you can see, because of the missing values, ggplot's "mean" line appears jagged and misleading.**

[image: ggplot points and mean line]

### ***Is there a way to force ggplot to calculate the mean based on the LINES that it drew, not the raw data?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could interpolate the missing values and then plot:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Starting data frame
dframe = dframe %>% filter(!is.na(height))

dframe %>% 
  complete(date, nesting(name)) %>% 
  arrange(name, date) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(heightImp = approx(height, xout=date)$y,
         imputed.flag = ifelse(is.na(height), "Imputed", "Measured")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, heightImp)) +
   geom_line(aes(group = name), color = "blue") +
   geom_point(aes(colour=imputed.flag)) +
   stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line", size = 1) +
   scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","blue")) +
   labs(colour="") +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

You could also just plot the regression line, which is the conditional mean at each x-value, subject to the constraint that the regression line is actually a straight line, rather than the piecewise linear result you get when connecting the mean values calculated separately at each x-value:

```
ggplot(dframe, aes(date, height)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = name), color = "blue") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", colour="black", se=FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

You can also fit a more complex regression function. The code below shows a third-order polynomial and a B-spline with three degrees of freedom. They're the same in this case (the black curve for the third-order polynomial is "underneath" the red curve for the B-spline), due to the small number of time points, but will be different in general. The point is that you can fit a wide range of functions using linear regression, depending on what you think is appropriate for your data and subject matter. (Another factor in this case is that you have repeated measures for each subject, so the appropriate model would take account of that by using a hierarchical model (see the `lme4` or `nlme` packages)):

```
ggplot(dframe, aes(date, height)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = name), color = "blue") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y ~ poly(x, 3), colour="black", se=FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y ~ splines::bs(x,df=3), colour="red", se=FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I was afraid it was going to be ugly. ha! I've done something kind of like this before, I was just hoping that there was some innate ggplot capacity for this. This will do the trick though - thanks for the rapid fire response, @eipi10! The regression line won't cut it for my "real" data (it has bumps and valleys).

Comment: @Nova A regression line shouldn't have bumps and valleys

Comment: haha,  I meant that the distribution of my data is not linear, so a regression line wouldn't be appropriate. :P

Comment: The appropriate regression line to fit your data depends on subject matter knowledge. If you think the "real" conditional mean is better represented by a curved line, then you could fit a more complex regression function. I've added another example for this.